# Python multiprocessing and an imported module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have two processing running that access an imported module like that:

```
import foo

def bar():
  while True:
    foo.a = True

def baz():
  while True:
    print foo.a

p1 = Process(target=bar)
p2 = Process(target=baz)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

It seems that each process have their own instance of module foo, `bar()` changes value to True, but in `baz()` it's False. Any workaround?

Comment: Lookup `queue`s and `pipe`s

Comment: @muddyfish that's just for communication though, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, apart from that, you can't change objects that aren't thread friendly.

Comment: Doesn't `Process` mean a real process (ie with separate memory space)? In that case it's expected that they have own instances of modules. What do you want to do? Communicate? In the documentation it says how to do that (queues, pipes and shared memory).

Comment: @skyking not really communicate, but force them to have the same instance of foo. Or pass it as an argument somehow

Comment: One way you could do it could be to pickle the object and pass it through a pipe but that would be really nasty

Comment: @akalikin If you want to have the same instance then maybe `thread`s or `threading` is the way to go (I don't know if `Process` means a separate process, but I suspect that). Without knowing what you actually are trying to do it's hard to say what would be a suitable solution.

Comment: It seems that you do not have a thorough understanding of processes and memory isolation. While people can give you some answers, you will likely encounter a slew of bugs, many nondeterministic, because of synchronization issue.

Comment: @skyking yep, Thread works good, i'll give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Unlike threads, separate processes do not share memory.
There are ways, however, [to share data between separate processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). 
One way is to use a `mp.Value`:

**foo.py**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
a = mp.Value('b', False)
```

then the script

```
import time
import foo
import multiprocessing as mp

def bar():
    foo.a.value = True

def baz():
    for i in range(10**5):
        print foo.a.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p2 = mp.Process(target=baz)
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p1 = mp.Process(target=bar)
    p1.start()
```

yields

```
0
0
0
...
1
1
1
...
```

---

For sharing a boolean value, an `mp.Event` is perhaps a better option:

**foo.py**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
a = mp.Event()
```

**script.py**:

```
def bar():
    foo.a.set()

def baz():
    for i in range(10**5):
        print foo.a.is_set()
```

yields

```
False
False
False
...
True
True
True
...
```